# how to link HTML with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I've tried to do something from another post, didn't work.
How do I combine those two codes?
HTML CODE:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using SvivaTeamVersion3.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<p><button onclick="" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white w3-border"><b>ADD NEW REPORT »</b></button></p>
```

Code that I want to add to the onclick event:

```
if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <script>
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        </script>
    } else {
        <script>
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        </script>
    }
```

Controller (Home Controller) - I added here the checkLoginStatus function to handle the problem right now :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SvivaTeamVersion3.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

    public IActionResult Index()
            {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        public ActionResult CheckLoginStatus()
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Login");
            return View("~/Views/Report/Create.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to add a event to a button using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846815/how-to-add-a-event-to-a-button-using-razor)

Comment: How's your `startup.cs` looks like? Are you using  `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` there? In addition please share your controller to investigate the details.

Comment: Yea I have those, Adding the controller.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood that you need a conditional access to your page based on User authentication state, so this should work:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using SvivaTeamVersion3.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<p><button onclick="" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white w3-border"><b>ADD NEW REPORT »</b></button></p>

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <script>
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    </script>
} else {
    <script>
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    </script>
}
```

A better approach would be to use `OnGet()` method in your razor page model:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    if(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
    else
        Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

**Update:** based on the update to question your application is using MVC. So, for authentication it's would be easier to use the `[Authorize]` attribute. I'll assume that your `Create` page
exists in `ReportController` according to view path provided in your question:

```
@* Add a link to your page *@
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Report">Privacy</a>

public class ReportController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This will prevent anonymous users from accessing that page without authentication, or you can do any other logic required before returning the view and based on that redirect to another page.

Otherwise, you can use a form and submit to specific action in your controller then execute whatever logic you need:

```
<form asp-action="CheckLoginStatus" asp-controller="Home">
    <button type="submit">Add Report</button>
</form>
```

It's easier to use `RedirectToAction("Create", "Report")` when redirecting internally between controllers/actions and use `Redirect()` for external links.

Comment: Yea I have a function like this and I am calling it from the HTML by a "using" statement.
When I click it works perfectly normal but in the link, I see "/ControllerName/FunctionName"

Comment: I don't understand what you need exactly, is the code I provided resolve your issue? If not, explain more and what do you mean by but in the link, I see "/ControllerName/FunctionName"?

Comment: SEll, I have a button on the home screen. When the button has been clicked it'll check if the user is logged in or not. If logged in, redirect him to a "report" page and if not then redirect the user to the login page. Because I use a "using" statement I have a function in the controller that redirects the user if he's logged in, so when I click the button the new link is ~/controllername/functionname

Comment: I understood before that your app is using Razor Pages but after adding the update with your controller, I've updated my answer to include MVC controller

Comment: Let me know if that worked with you and answered your question

Comment: @David can you please check the updated answer? And let me know if it works. If so, please accept as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use c#code in js,you can try to use:

```
<script>
var url;
$(function(){
    url=@SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)?"url1":"url2";
    window.location.href =url;
})
</script>
```

Comment: how do I add it to a named function

Comment: also, by using your method I get this:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: True is not defined
    at Check_If_logged_In ((index):121:37)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):116:147)